# Why is our URLSession object a variable and not a constant

Tags: swift, urlsession

I'm following a tutorial on consuming REST API's to get JSON back from a third party server.  We are building out a networkProcessor class in which we will be able to use it by creating instances of this class in ViewControllers in order to make url sessions for network calls.  I noticed that the author declared the session placeholder as a variable and not a constant which went against what I've learned while using Xcode which is to always consider using constants first.  Is there a specific reason why the author may have chosen to make this a variable and not a constant?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import Foundation


class NetworkProcessor {


    lazy var configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    lazy var session: URLSession = URLSession.init(configuration: self.configuration)

    let url: URL

    //since it is a class we need to initalize this class
    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you can't have a `lazy let` property though there isn't much reason for it to be lazy either.

Comment: @dan why wouldn't it be much reason for it to be lazy?  Is it because we are creating the class in which it will be used in an abstract way?  What I'm trying to say is, could we pass in these those parameters when when initialize this class?

Answer (score 1):

When you use keyword lazy you can't use it with let keyword at the same time. Lazy properties must be variables but not constants.